# On the right path?

Tags: expressions

Suppose someone is trying to solve some math problem and he has the right idea to attack it, but still need more time to figure out details.

When I want to encourage him, should I use "You are on the right path" or "You are on the right track"? Or maybe some other more common expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of these two, the second is definitely preferred, and super common. This is especially common from math professors =).